# Как сделать и инициализировать двухмерный список в одну строчку в C#?

Tags: c#, list

Мне надо сделать двухмерный список в C# и сразу же его инициализировать в одну строчку. Так вот как это можно сделать?

Comment: Для инициализации используйте фигурные скобки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<List<string>> myList = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string> { "1", "2", "3" },
    new List<string> { "4", "5", "6" },
    new List<string> { "7", "8", "9" },
};
```

Comment: Технически это не двумерный список, а список списков, что немного другое.

Comment: А есть ли тогда вообще двумерный список? Класс Lookup?